# Decrypt decompressed python code in correct format

Tags: python, encryption, base64

I have a python code which has been decompressed and enrypted which i would like to see the actual code.
I have even been able to see code but still some part has zeroes.
I am doing import zlib

> > > import base64
> > >       print(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('blaaaa......
> > >       Can any one help me what I need to do to see the code in actual original format.

The python code I am trying to decrypt is http://pastebin.com/zz703Dim
The decrypted code I get doing print in python is http://pastebin.com/8MmCTuK0

can any one help me please.
thanks

Comment: It seams to me that decrypted code is absolutely normal but it was obfuscasted. There is no way to get original code after obfuscation.

Comment: But I have been able to get original code with other python code.this one has zlib.decompress hence its different.

Comment: It makes no difference what method was used to encrypt and compress code. An original code was altered before other modifications. Read about obfuscation. All variables and methods names were changed to meaningless random strings and resulting code became harder to comprehend. Reason is very simple: to make it difficult to reverse-engineer algorithm.